# Change the visibility of "n" rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the table like below with "n" numbers of rows.

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
    <span class="more">Show more</span>
```

Initially on page load, I want to show only two rows. And if i click "more" link, i just want to visible or show  3 more rows for every click.

How to get this with jquery. Example code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce9UV/3/)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by hiding everything but the first two tr's with css:

```
table tr {display:none;}
table tr:first-child, table tr:nth-child(2) {display:block}​
```

Then get the last visible tr's index, and show the next three etc.

```
$('.more')​.on('click', function() {
    var vis = $('table tr:visible').last().index();
    $('table tr').slice(vis, vis+4).show();
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce9UV/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide remaining `<tr>` using CSS3 `nth-child` selector:

```
​tr:nth-child(n+4) {
    display:none;
}​
```

And then use JQuery on click of Show more link to show them:

```
​$('.more')​.click(function() {
    $('tr').show();
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/BNrKn/